# Cooling with salt water

Tags: power-electronics, cooling

This might not be a strictly EE question, but I figure people here have experience.

How can I arrange water cooling of power electronics with sea salt water?

There will have to be certain filters to reduce any debris, of course.

How an aluminum heat sink behave in salt water? Is any specific surface finish better than others? Do people even do it?

Comment: `How an aluminum heat sink behave in salt water?` corrodes.

Comment: You might want to look at systems and the materials employed for cooling internal combustion engines using salt water. Some are 'open' systems and some use a secondary heat exchanger to transfer heat from fresh water/antifreeze to sea water. In the case of electronics a heat pipe could also be considered.

Comment: You use aluminum-bronze or nickel-aluminum-bronze in salt water = expensive.

Comment: Besides corrosion, I guess you also have to worry about algae and barnacles: https://news.microsoft.com/source/features/sustainability/project-natick-underwater-datacenter/

Comment: Speaking from sailboat experience. Anodized aluminum will corrode some, but the serious corrosion is where you have dissimilar metals, stainless steel fasteners on the aluminum.

Comment: Do you need filters? How big is this system? If it's small enough, seems a lot simpler to just blind tap mounting holes a block and submerge the underside of the block in seawater than to pipe seawater which would need filtering and even more use of non-corroding materials.

Comment: Maybe use a salt-water-safe heat exchanger and traditional liquid cooling components on your end.

Comment: For ships: You typically use two systems, fresh water to extract heat to heat exchanger; & sea water to heat exchanger to sea.  Sea water forms ions which will form batteries with dissimilar metal and eat away materials.  Faster the water move across surface the faster the corrision.

Comment: @DKNguyen honestly I don't know yet most of the answers

Comment: So are there other materials that would replace aluminum? Or maybe a way to live with corrosion?

Comment: @rdtsc I am trying to avoid extra systems for now. Storing coolant on board requires additional pump and heat exchanger/fan/whatever, things become messy.

Comment: +1 on the heat exchanger approach. Passivated 316 stainless steel sanitary pipe and fittings are generally suitable for pumping seawater, and are commonly used in industry.

Comment: You really do not have enough information in your question for us to even answer the question.  How much power?  Application.  Ships use cathodic protection via sacrificial anodes or impressed current for exterior of ship and sacrificial anodes for interior tanks.

Comment: @Polynomial I thought 316 had issues in seawater? At least in non pristine mechanical operating conditions.

Comment: @DKNguyen Good quality passivated 316 is usually fine for seawater, unless you're pulling in rocks or something that'd scratch away at the surface, but there should be a trap on the intake to stop that anyway. Needs to be passivated though, otherwise the unoxidised iron on the surface will rust like nobody's business. You can get PTFE lined stuff for more adverse environments but the price goes up.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat that's because i don't know much more. Heat to dissipate is between 800W and 3000W.

Comment: Then we cannot help you.  You need to do some research and then ask us a question.  Zinc, aluminum and magnesium are three metals used in sacrificial anodes, as in, the aluminum forms a battery with a steel hull and gets eaten away to protect lesser galvanic materials like steel, as in, prevents the steel from rusting.  Your solution depends upon power and application.

Comment: I think i did get a lot of help from these comments. You can't design for me, that's true. But enough folks over here shared enough stuff. I guess if I came here AFTER all my research was done, I wouldn't ask questions, right?